# Mongo aggregations with multiple different sorts

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

So I'm kind of new to Mongo aggregations and after a lot of researching and googling I can't figure out how to do a particular query.

Say I have many documents with the following format:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  client: "Some Client",
  type: "Some Type",
  firstUsed: 2021-01-05T13:23:37.000+0000
  lastUsed: 2021-05-05T18:11:23.000+0000
}
```

What I'm trying to do is group all the documents by type (for a particular client), and then get the first `firstUsed` datetime and the last `lastUsed` datetime.

I've been playing with aggregations but after doing a `$match` on the client, `$group` on the type, I can only figure out then how to get only one of the dates I need.

Sorting by `firstUsed` and getting the first document is fine, but then getting the last document doesnt mean I'm getting the correct `lastUsed`.

How do I re-sort and get the last `lastUsed` datetime while keeping the already found `firstUsed`?

Hope that makes sense,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you said I think you are trying to get the earliest first date and the greatest last data. You can use `$max` and `$min` for the dates. Here's a solution that you can use:

```
{
$group: {
  _id: "$type",
  firstUsed: {
    $min: "$firstUsed"
  },
  lastUsed: {
    $max: "$lastUsed"
  }, 
 }
}
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/v-QK2ItL3uq

Comment: I cannot believe it's that simple... Thank you very much Ali! It's been a long day...